# How to hide and call an element of a list in R?

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have a R list:

```
ls<-list(a="a",b="b",c="c")
```

Is there a way I can hide element `b`? such like:

```
> ls
$a
[1] "a"

$c
[1] "c"
```

And if it's hidden, how do I call it back like `ls$b` or `ls$.b`? I am asking this is because the element b may be very large and I don't want it list out but just used for the next analysis.

Comment: What do you mean "hide"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also specify a new class and a new print function for your objet :

```
x <- vector("list", 3L)
names(x) <- letters[1:3]
x[[1]] <- 1
x[[2]] <- "the element to hide"
x[[3]] <- "a"
class(x) <- c("bob", "list")
attr(x, "hidden") <- "b"
print.bob <- function (x) {
    hid <- attr(x, "hidden")
    print(x[!names(x) %in% hid])
    }
x
$a
[1] 2

$c
[1] 4
# but
length(x)
[1] 3
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to avoid printing element `ls$b`. These will work

```
ls<-list(a="a",b="b",c="c")
print(ls[-2])                      # print everything but second elememt
print(ls[which(names(ls)!="b")])   # print everything but element named "b"
```

Comment: If a function's return is print(ls[-2]), the ls[2] can not be called any more, right?

Comment: Yes, but this is equivalent to returning `ls[-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this meets your needs:

```
output.limit <- 3 # use own value
test <- list(a="a", b=c("b1", "b2", "b3"), c="c", d=c("1", "2", "3", "4"), e="e")
lapply(test, function(x) if(length(x)<output.limit) x else "<too large...>")
```

Console output:

```
$a
[1] "a"

$b
[1] "<too large...>"

$c
[1] "c"

$d
[1] "<too large...>"

$e
[1] "e"
```